# Категория зависит от страны OpenCart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать чтоб категории открывались при выборе страны (как на скриншоте)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще я думаю это реализовать во так:

1) Будет главная категория Ebay (меню под номером 1 на скриншоте)

2) В категории Ebay будут подкатегории - это страны: США, Германия, Великобритания (На скриншоте меню под номером 2)

3) В каждой из подкатегорий стран(США, Германия, Великобритания) будут свои подкатегории

Вот я реализовал (меню 1 на скриншоте) так что я убрал категории в админке, и напрямую вписал в файле шаблона product/category.tpl просто вывод категорий, то есть они будут доступны только когда верхнее меню уже выбрано, а вот как еще сделать разделение на страны ?

Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Answer (score 0):

Не надо делать харкод.
сделай у Ebay - 3 подкатегории (страны), а у стран - свои подкатегории.

Comment: я так и делаю, но мне нужно чтоб категории и подкатегории были в разных местах на одной страницу

Comment: Ну это тебе надо перелеоывать модуль категорий. Стандартный не позволит такого сделать.